# Should a design class diagram show private operations?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Should a design class diagram show private operations? I guess that a design class diagram only has to show public methods and the most important private attributes. Am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are designing the *implementation* of the class as well, there's no reason to include private members in the design diagram. Private members serve the purpose of being the *implementation details* of the class and generally the implementation *does not matter* as long as it adheres to the public contract.